# Doctrine Caching - upgrading to PHP 5/6

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, apc, php-5.6

I'm in the process of upgrading my server from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.6.  One of the performance enhancments I use is to cache Doctrine results:

```
$query->useResultCache('cache_key', 300);
```

I have Symfony configured to use APC for caching:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
        result_cache_driver: apc
        query_cache_driver: apc
```

In PHP 5.6, APC is removed, so I will install the APCu extension.  Does the Symfony configuration need to be updated to use APCu, or will the `apc` cache drivers work with APCu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The APCu interface is the same as it was with APC. That's why you do not need to adjust your configuration: https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu

Edit: the namespace has changed from `apc_` to `apcu_` in later versions, so in order to guarantee BC they now introduced a specific wrapper: https://pecl.php.net/package/apcu_bc